# Rails i18n use array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, erb, rails-i18n

I got a situation, there are many kinds of receipt in my project. I store them in `integer`.

In `i18n` file, I declare translation in this way.

```
hash[:"Receipt"] = {
    :"receipt_choice1"            => "Rc1",
    :"choise_detail2"             => "Rc_datail1",
    :"receipt_choice2"            => "Rc2",
    :"choise_detail2"             => "Rc_datail2",
    :"receipt_choice2"            => "Rc3",
    :"choise_detail2"             => "Rc_datail3",
  }
```

However, it's not convenient for me. In view, I need to write `if, else` syntax to choose which term I need. Like this.

```
<% if receipt.type == 1 %>
  <p> <%= t(:"receipt.Receipt.receipt_choice1") </p>
  <p> <%= t(:"receipt.Receipt.choise_detail2") </p>
<% elsif receipt.type == 2 %>
  <p> <%= t(:"receipt.Receipt.receipt_choice1") </p>
  <p> <%= t(:"receipt.Receipt.choise_detail2") </p>
...
```

Is there a way I can use array to declare? Like

`<%= t(:"receipt.Receipt[receipt.type]") %>`

Or is there a better way I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:"..."` symbol syntax allows string interpolation just like double quoted strings so you can say things like:

```
<p><%= t(:"receipt.Receipt.receipt_choice#{receipt.type}") %></p>
<p><%= t(:"receipt.Receipt.choise_detail#{receipt.type}") %></p>
```

Also, the `t` helper eventually calls `I18n.translate` and [that doesn't care if you give it strings or symbols](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/v0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb#L61):

```
# Key can be either a single key or a dot-separated key (both Strings and Symbols
# work). <em>E.g.</em>, the short format can be looked up using both:
#   I18n.t 'date.formats.short'
#   I18n.t :'date.formats.short'
```

so you can skip the symbols and just use strings:

```
<p><%= t("receipt.Receipt.receipt_choice#{receipt.type}") %></p>
<p><%= t("receipt.Receipt.choise_detail#{receipt.type}") %></p>
```